# Combining Google Places API and Facebook Places API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-places-api, foursquare

This may be a simple question but I can not find answer over the web or any docs. I have app which shows business places around users and their details. I have built it using Google Places API. [As written in the usage limit section](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/usage), Google Places API has a usage limit of 150000 requests/day. My app has been downloaded over 10000 times on different Android markets combined and looking through google dev console; I predict that app will cross the limits nearly within 6 months to 1 year period.
So, All I want to do is to integrate another api and show combined results to users.
[Foursquare](https://developer.foursquare.com) came first to my mind. But I got disappointed when I read the terms and conditions:

> Venues Database Usage ... Don't perform a search across both
>   foursquare and Google Places, then return a combination of their
>   results/data

Another option I found is [Facebook Places API](https://www.facebook.com/places/), which has less restriction over limits. But the problem is neither [terms and conditions of Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) nor [of Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) says about aggregating search results with other data sources.

Can anyone have any idea about this? If anyone know about this kind of problem, please help me out.

Comment: Why don't u just purchase a license for google maps as you are going over the limit? https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage#purchase-m4w

Comment: @Simon Perhaps I can do if i put ads in my app. But i don't like ads and want to keep my app free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although your question is not clear on whether you ever intend to monetize your app or whether you've already done that (which would enable you to go for a work API or another premium one, but I guess you need to work out your own finances), I have the following suggestions for you.

I have used a few APIs during my programming life, and when it comes to relative accuracy and reliability, Google APIs have been the best in general.

Unfortunately the places API does not have a pay-as-you-go billing system like the directions API where we get billed USD 0.50 for every 1000 over-limit requests. Google work APIs can be very expensive for small-medium scale business. This leaves you with only one glimmer of hope. [This google documentation](https://www.google.com/work/mapsearth/products/mapsapi.html) suggests that we can get:

> Free uplifts for complying applications

Further looking into this, I found [this](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/usage#request-uplift) page, which spells out the exact requirements to get an uplift, and I suppose this is very viable for you.

If you still think of going for another API instead of Google, I would suggest reading [this](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-each-Places-API) article, ehich gives a nie comparison between the different APIs. (please note that limits/pricing details may be outdated.)

Finally, on using different APIs together, I would use different services together if they do not explicitly state that it is forbidden. However, the biggest issue here would be displaying data in a map. Most providers prohibit you from displaying their data in another providers map or vice versa. read about this in the terms and conditions too. Still, don't count on me or any other stranger for legal opinion. 
Hope this gives you some idea.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. What I want to do is to gather reviews from facebook places api and to show business information from Google places api. Is is possible?

Comment: Technically possible,  but I can't elaborate on this, haven't tried it. Google does say that you cannot use data from another api inside a google map, but does not say you cant use them in the same app. Let me know how you progress. it is an interesting idea.

Comment: and as you have wrote : 'whether you ever intend to monetize your app or whether you've already done that (which would enable you to go for a work API or another premium on'; if I put ads in my app, would I have to pay google for that?  WIll Google disallow me if I put ads in the screens where place api has been used?

Comment: NO no, if you use their ads, they will pay you. I suggested that because you could use that revenue to go for a paid work API.

Comment: AFAIK no problem with using ads with the apis. You can double check that with the Google documentation.

Comment: and one more question: "However, the biggest issue here would be displaying data in a map. Most providers prohibit you from displaying their data in another providers map or vice versa". So, if I use Facebook places api to get location of the place and show it on Google Maps; will it violate Google Maps TOS? I can't see any reference though.

Comment: From google's TOS, you can use google places API data only with google maps. And if you use places data on another map, you need to show the powered by google image. Read this: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/attributions#map
I'm not familiar with facebook APIs that much; will have to go through it if they have similar restrictions, but from google's TOS, the condition above does not apply for your scenario mentioned in this comment AFAIK.